# NodeJS Async ForEachOf - Stuck in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm completely stumped here. I've got a piece of NodeJS code and I'm using the Async library's forEachOf function. The code should loop through each item in **result1**, create a **tempNode** object from it, and then construct & send a SQL query (I'm using the mysql package for the .query function). Once this comes back, it should add this information to the tempNode and add to the **returnObject** array.

The problem is that processing appears to hang as soon as the callback() function is reached. I can put a console.log statement anywhere before callback() and verify that everything's coming through OK (the SQL query works, for example), but it never executes the resolve code (No error is displayed either). It also doesn't seem to go through the loop again, as I've tried logging the value of 'x', but I only ever get one output of '0'.

Here's the code snippet. It's inside a function that returns a promise, hence the **resolve** and **reject**.

```
var returnObject = [];
    if (result1.length !=0) {

    // ! This forEachOf gets stuck ! 
    async.forEachOf(result1, function(o_1, x, callback) {
        let tempNode = {
            NODE: result1[x].node,
            FIELDS: [
                {"ID": result1[x].id },
                {"SITE": result1[x].site }
            ] 
        }
        // Construct model query using the node identifier
        var q_model = `SELECT model FROM *TABLE* WHERE name = '${result1[x].node}'`;

        // Second query to determine the BTS model
        mysqlPooler.query(q_model, function(err,result2,fields) {

            if (result2.length !=0 && result2) {
                tempNode.FIELDS.push({"MODEL":result2[0].model});
                returnObject.push(tempNode);
            }
            else {
                reject("ERROR: No MODEL");
            }
            console.log(result2);
            // Done processing this iteration
            callback();

            }); 

    }), function(err)
        console.log(err);
        resolve (returnObject);
         }
    } 
    else 
    {
        reject("ERROR");
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your query well constructed?  do you get any output from the query try isolating each step to detect the issue.

Comment: Hi, yeah the query part seems to be OK. The output of result2 after it comes back is exactly what I expect. Even doing a **console.log(returnObject)** right before callback() gives me exactly what I need

Comment: What is `reject`? Don't mix promise code with the `async` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there was an extra "**)**" near the very end, and a missing "**{**" right before the callback function definition. The last few lines need to be changed to:

```
}, function(err) 
  {
  console.log(err);
  resolve (returnObject);
  });
} 
else 
{
  reject("ERROR");
}
```

Basically, the behavior can be explained by the fact that the third argument (ie, the callback function) to async.ForEachOf() function was undefined, due to improper brackets/formatting. Thus it seems like it didn't know what to do when the loop was finished!

Comment: wouldnt you be getting a trailing bracket error which is quite easy to debug?

Comment: Interestingly I didn't get any error. I'm using VS code, I feel like I may have messed it up further by adding brackets in the wrong place when I was getting errors. Perhaps an extension could've helped me? Thanks